# Slider Bokeh Plot callback customJS

Tags: python, slider, data-visualization, bokeh, interactive

I am trying to create an interactive Bokeh plot with 2 sliders.

My code is as below

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from bokeh.layouts import column, row
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CustomJS, Slider
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show


def my_fun(A0=10, k=2):
    
    x = np.arange(0,5,0.5)
    A = A0*np.exp(-k*x)
    B = A0 - A0*np.exp(-k*x)
    
    return A, B, x

A, B, x = my_fun(A0=10, k=2)

output = np.stack((x,A,B),axis=1)

output = pd.DataFrame(data=output)
output.columns = ['x','A','B']
output.head(10)

source = output

plot = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)

plot.scatter('x', 'A', source=source, color='blue', size = 7.5)
plot.line('x', 'A', source=source, line_color='blue', line_width=2)

plot.scatter('x', 'B', source=source, color='red', size = 7.5)
plot.line('x', 'B', source=source, line_color='red', line_width=2)

plot.xaxis.axis_label = 'Time'
plot.yaxis.axis_label = 'Stock Price'

slider_A = Slider(start=5, end=10, value=10, step=.1, title="A0")
slider_k = Slider(start=0.5, end=4, value=2, step=.1, title="k")

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code="""
        var data = source.data;
        var f = cb_obj.value
        var x = data['x']
        var y = data['y']
        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            y[i] = Math.pow(x[i], f)
        }
        source.change.emit();
    """)


slider.js_on_change('value', callback)

layout = column(
        column(slider_A, slider_k),
        plot,
)

show(layout)
```

Output of the code is expected html figure (screen shot below).

[image]

When slider is moved, output is not changing (of course not) because ***callback*** isn't defined correctly (I know that !). I don't know how to modify CustomJS part because its Javascript(?).

How to call `my_fun` inside `callback` or `CustomJS` to update the output for new input values, i.e. `A0`, `k`?

Thank you

Comment: There is no way at all to call `my_fun` from a standalone HTML output. At the point the content is displayed everything only lives in the browser so only JavaScript is available. If you want to call real Python code, that is what the Bokeh server is for. Otherwise you have to make JavaScript to do what you need.

Comment: @bigreddot Oh okay. Thank you for the clarification ! So if I manage to write a code in JavaScript inside CustomJS, will it work?

Comment: Yes, there are lots of examples of CustomJS examples in the docs https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html